# What does "(#o4, #x4, ?\C-d)" mean here?

Tags: eval-expression

I use `m-x eval-expression` to evaluate a very simple lisp code:

```
 ( + 1 3)
```

And I got my result like this

[image]

What does the symbols `(#o4, #x4, ?\C-d)` mean in this context?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are alternative representations of an integer with their reader literals for octal, hexadecimal and char notation.  In other words, evaluating the octal number `#o4`, hexadecimal number `#x4` or char `?\C-d` yields 4.

edit: FWIW, this behaviour seems to be [a bug](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=20691) and should be fixed on master (and hopefully become part of the upcoming 25.1 release).